# WARNING: Hidden import "pygame._view" not found

Tags: python, pygame, exe

Essentially, I'm trying to convert a simple program that displays lots of mouse information to a window, just as a side project. I've tried almost every solution that people have had, but nothing is working. I am using pyinstaller and python-to-exe.

Tried changing file directories, every single option in pyinstaller, and changing loop functions.

```py
import pyautogui
from pygame import *
import time
import keyboard
import logging
import datetime

logging.basicConfig(filename="mouse_log.log", filemode="w",
                    format='%(message)s', level=logging.DEBUG)

pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((250, 95))
pygame.display.set_caption("Cursor Info")
font = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 15)
title_font = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 16)
icon = pygame.image.load("MouseController.png").convert_alpha()
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)


def main():
    previous_pos = pyautogui.position()
    running = True
    while running:

        mx, my = pyautogui.position()
        current_pos = mx, my
        msx = current_pos[0] - previous_pos[0]
        msy = current_pos[1] - previous_pos[1]
        mouse_color = pyautogui.pixel(mx, my)
        if msx == 0 and msy == 0:
            moving = False
        else:
            moving = True

        cords = font.render("Position:  x = {}, y = {}".format(mx, my), False, (0, 0, 0))
        color = font.render("Current Color:  {}".format(mouse_color), False, (0, 0, 0))
        is_moving = font.render("Currently Moving:  {}".format(str(moving)), False, (0, 0, 0))
        speed = font.render("Speed:  x = {}, y = {}".format(msx, msy), False, (0, 0, 0))
        log = title_font.render("Press Alt+C to log all aspects", True, (0, 0, 0))

        pygame.display.flip()
        pygame.Surface.fill(screen, (255, 255, 255))

        screen.blit(cords, (5, 0))
        screen.blit(color, (5, 15))
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 0), (211, 13, 30, 22))
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 0), (211, 13, 31, 23))
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, mouse_color, (212, 14, 28, 20))
        screen.blit(is_moving, (5, 30))
        screen.blit(speed, (5, 45))
        screen.blit(log, (20, 75))
        previous_pos = current_pos

        if keyboard.is_pressed('C') and keyboard.is_pressed('Alt'):
            logging.debug("TIME:  {}".format(datetime.datetime.now().time()))
            logging.debug("POSITION:  x = {}, y = {}".format(mx, my))
            logging.debug("COLOR:  {}".format(mouse_color))
            logging.debug("MOVING:  {}".format(str(moving)))
            logging.debug("SPEED:  x = {}, y = {}".format(msx, msy))
            logging.debug("=========")

            time.sleep(0.2)

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
                pygame.quit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The output of the exe file in every case is that it failed to run with a critical error and failure to run the script. I have no clue what is going on, please help!

Comment: I have no clue with the error that you have encountered as there no posting on error message. Perhaps you would make your program simpler and test it first with python. Only with successful resukts then you compile to exe. Then make sure exe file will still work. Then modify you program with more features and repeat the process again. Hope this would guide you.

Comment: UPDATE: I looked through the log files that were given, and found this line `missing module named pyautogui`. Now I know that pyautogui isn't importing, but I dont know how to fix it. Thanks

Comment: You can just open a python shell and run `import pyautogui`. If it is unsuccessful,  try to install it.  If you running python 3 in Linux, do this `pip3 install pyautogui`. Otherwise just install via `pip install pyautogui`

Comment: Okay, I've now done both, and yet still when I run `import pyautogui` it says that it doesn't exist. I will keep trying

Comment: Then just install it. See https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html.  Another reason is that you install pyautogui using one python version but run your script using another version.  You could follow the instruction to see path that your python is looking for the library: https://www.dummies.com/programming/python/how-to-find-path-information-in-python/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## **For Anyone Wondering, Here Was The Solution:**

**1.** The first thing that I did was run the python file from the command prompt, using `python {script name}.py` in the folder where it was. I figured out that I had not installed a module on my machine that was by default on my IDE (PyCharm), which turned out to be the `keyboard` module. Make sure its properly installed and it should work fine.

**2. (VERY IMPORTANT)** Check for multiple installs of python. As I found out later, the reason why certain modules such as `pyautogui` were not working were because they were by default being installed to a different version of python that I also had installed on my system. In my case, `pyautogui` was being installed automatically to Python version 3.6.4 instead of 3.7.3 which all of the other modules were being run off of. Just delete the version of python that you aren't using and re-install the packages and it should work then.

**3.** Unless you have a section of the script to account for the lack of it, if your script includes any images of any sort (excluding the icon image) or any other imported files, they have to be in the same place as where they are specified in the code or it will not work. If you are doing a window based program, the window will pop up, appear black, and then a fatal error message will appear. As long as all images and outside media are accessible, there should be no graphical errors.

**4. (TROUBLESHOOT)** Obviously, the **FATAL ERROR** message you get from running the .exe file is no use for trying to solve any issues, however if you are using `pyinstaller` to build it should create an `__pycache__` folder which contains a more friendly .pyc file that will actually give you errors and things that are going wrong with the code. Try this if nothing here is working.